# Apache Spark: Get rid of empty partitions without data movement

Tags: apache-spark, streaming, apache-kafka, rdd

I have a `spark streaming` application which listens from `Kafka` topic. Every `n` minutes, it get a chunk of data as `RDD`. I am maintaining another `RDD` in which the new chunk is `Union`-ed and then it is `filter`ed. It is like a sliding window on a timeline. So my code is like this:

```
val slidingRDD : RDD[myObject] =_

// In streaming context
myKafkaInputDStream.transform{ rdd => deserialize(rdd) }
myKafkaInputDStream.forEachRDD{ chunkRDD => slidingRDD = slidingRDD.union(chunkRDD) }
// do some more stuff
slidingRDD.filter( myObject.timestamp > threshold )
```

Since I have two partitions on `Kafka` topic, I get two partitions on `chunkRDD`. On every run, the number of partitions in `slidingRDD` increments by two. The `filter` results in some empty partitions and some partitions with very few objects.

**Question**:

Since, an empty partition also spawns a task, can there be a major performance impact? Is there a way to remove empty partitions only, without any data movement (or avoiding `repartition`)?